# huge traffic from POST 123.249.24.233/POST_ip_port.php

Tags: nginx, logging, wordpress

```
222.186.129.5 - - [19/Jun/2015:16:56:28 +0000] "POST http://123.249.24.233/POST_ip_port.php HTTP/1.1" 301 184 "http://123.249.24.233/POST_ip_port.phpAccept: */*" "Mozi$
222.186.30.111 - - [19/Jun/2015:16:56:29 +0000] "POST http://123.249.24.233/POST_ip_port.php HTTP/1.1" 301 184
```

There are so many traffic with POST method from IP 222.186.*.* so i got high cpu usage.
My question,
is it attacked?
how to avoid it? (i don't want to block those ip), 
And, i don't understand about the log, it says "POST **http://123.249.24.233/POST_ip_port.php** HTTP/1.0" in the normal POST the url should come from local but it is from external.

Btw i use nginx, php5-fpm and wordpress and i got so many POST to xmlrpc.php but i have solved it by remove and add rules.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's only Layer 7; just install something such as DDOS Deflate or null route the IP Range.

To null route the IP:

```
route add -host 222.186.129.X reject
ip route get 222.186.129.x
```

**Output**

```
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

To null route the whole subnet:

```
route add -net 222.186.0/24 gw 127.0.0.1 lo
```

Or to install DDOS Deflate:

```
wget http://www.inetbase.com/scripts/ddos/install.sh
chmod 0700 install.sh
./install.sh
```

**(Uninstall) ->**

```
wget http://www.inetbase.com/scripts/ddos/uninstall.ddos
chmod 0700 uninstall.ddos
./uninstall.ddos
```

If the attack is still to big to handle I recommend contacting your ISP; however another option is to get a reverse proxy which has DDOS Protection from Layer 7 attacks such as http://x4b.net (Quite cheap soloution)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a warning. Even though it has become somewhat customary, it usually is not a good security practice running unknown unchecked scripts straight off the web.

Comment: Yes that is very true; however I can confirm that this script it highly trusted and has been checked. I have also checked it with VirusTotal.com and it's clean (https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/c58c2d439f809318d329ff43924e5e42459642d2c8ac7e96af2d56c52015ab3f/analysis/1434899259/)